# Using Tags to pass data between methods

Tags: android

Can you only set one Tag per object? I have a getView method in a Custom Adapter class and I would like to pass several pieces of data to my onClick function. I was able to pass a String fine, but I would also like to pass in the position variable and can't figure out how

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_grid_date, parent, false);
        }

        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendarDayButton);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

        gridcell.setTag("October");//This one gets passed fine
        gridcell.setTag(position);//How can I pass this one as well??


        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String getString = (String) view.getTag();
        int getInt = (int) view.getTag();
        selectedDay.setText(getString);
}
```

I tried setting an index to the tag like:

```
        gridcell.setTag(1, "October");
        gridcell.setTag(2, position);
```

but the app keeps crashing:

```
10-05 16:02:05.599  14723-14723/com.markfeldman.mycalendar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.markfeldman.mycalendar, PID: 14723
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.
        at android.view.View.setTag(View.java:17297)
        at com.markfeldman.mycalendar.GridCellAdapter.getView(GridCellAdapter.java:173)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1060)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: You need to write by yourself... `setTag(instanceOfYourObjectWhichContainsAllDataThatYouNeed)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have two options. You could create a POJO that contains all the data you want to pass to your View and then call `View#setTag(yourPojo)`.

Alternatively, you could set multiple tags on the View (as you have been trying to do). The problem is that the first argument to `View#setTag(int, Object)` is not just a simple `int`, it actually must be an [ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) as specified in the [SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)):

> The specified key should be an id declared in the resources of the
> application to ensure it is unique (see the ID resource type).

Fortunately it is fairly easy to define new IDs, the link above describes the process well.